# Segmentation Fault accessing array positions after realloc

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, realloc, memory-reallocation

Let's suppose I have this function:

```
void arrayExtendDouble(int **ptArr, int *size)
{    
    *ptArr = realloc(*ptArr, (*size * 2) * sizeof(int));


    for(int i = (*size * 2) - 1; i >= *size; i--)
        ptArr[i] = fib(i); //this will throw SEG FAULT

    *size *= 2;       
}
```

Note: I am a student and this is the valid resolution a teacher gave.

Now, the only way i can make this work is like this:

```
    void fibArrayExpand(int **ptArr, int *size)
    {    
        int *ptArrNew = realloc(*ptArr, (*size * 2) * sizeof(int));


        for(int i = (*size * 2) - 1; i >= *size; i--)
            ptArrNew[i] = fib(i);

        *size *= 2;       

        *ptArr = ptArrN;
    }
```

Supposedly the first one (teacher's) is correct and the second one (mine) it's not because i do extra steps not needed.

I would like to know why does it throw segmentation fault, is it supposed to do so or is the function well written?

Comment: that first one's bad in general. The naming of those variables causes some scope issues that are confusing. Yours is better but you forget to check if the result of `realloc` is `NULL`.

Comment: The first function is the teachers? It's wrong. Are you sure that `ptArr` is declared again as a local inside the function?

Comment: @RetiredNinja oh.. i see what you mean, no that's my bad, will edit the question. But still without that it seg faults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet isn't correct. `ptAtr` isn't the pointer to the ints; it's a pointer to another pointer, `*ptAtr`, which is the pointer to the ints. As such,

```
ptArr[i] = fib(i);
```

should be

```
(*ptArr)[i] = fib(i);
```

---

**Alternate explanation**

It's pretty easy to see the following code achieves the correct result:

```c
void arrayExtendDouble(int** arr_ptr, int* size_ptr)
{    
    // Copy values from caller.
    int* arr = *arr_ptr;
    int size = *size_ptr;

    arr = realloc(arr, (size * 2) * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = (size * 2) - 1; i >= size; i--)
        arr[i] = fib(i);

    size *= 2;

    // Pass back modified values to caller.
    *arr_ptr  = arr;
    *size_ptr = size;
}
```

You might notice that `arr` and `*arr_ptr` have the same value, and so do `size` and `size_ptr`. That means we could simply replace all instances of `arr` and `size` with `*arr_ptr` and `*size_ptr` respectively.

```c
void arrayExtendDouble(int** arr_ptr, int* size_ptr)
{    
    *arr_ptr = realloc(*arr_ptr, (*size_ptr * 2) * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = (*size_ptr * 2) - 1; i >= *size_ptr; i--)
        (*arr_ptr)[i] = fib(i);

    *size_ptr *= 2;
}
```

Note that `(*arr_ptr)[i] = fib(i);` is used instead of `arr[i] = fib(i);`. The first snippet you posted is therefore incorrect.

Comment: I'm really thankful for the extra time explaining! Imagine paying tuition and still need to resort to an online community because some teachers won't just admit they're wrong...
Once again, thanks!

Comment: woops, there was a missing `not` and a missing `*` in my explanation. wow. Fixed!